# Synonymize Update to Updates

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed there's a [updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates) tag and a [update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) tag, both with similar question counts and (best I can tell, I'm not a Wordpress guy) identical meanings. Neither has a tag wiki either.

Should these be synonymized to the same tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I merged both. *(filler content …)*